# Website Keeps Resizing on Mobile Device

Tags: ajax, html, css, bootstrap-4

SO Im finishing my website after building for almost a year and Im having a problem with the responsiveness of my website on my mobile devices. I cant seem to find out what the problem is. Please Help me figure this out before I go any further. Im using bootstrap 4 , and Ajax to load the pages and modals. This is last of the changes that I need to make to the website to make it responsive for mobile devices.

https://trillumonopoly.com

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MAIN</title>

<script>
/*

Suga Slider

Usage ---------

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#logos').suga({
    'transitionSpeed': 2000,
    'snap': false
  });
});

The markup should resemble the markup here

*/

$.fn.suga = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
      'transitionSpeed': 3000,
      'snap': false
  }, options);

  var $this = $(this);

  // add plugin specific classes
  $this.addClass('suga-slider-wrap');
  $this.children('ul').addClass('suga-slider-group');
  $this.find('li').addClass('suga-slide');  

  // caching $$$
  var $slide = $('.suga-slide'),
            $firstEl = $('.suga-slide:first'),
      $group = $('.suga-slider-group'),
      $wrap = $('.suga-slider-wrap');

  var slideWidth = $slide.outerWidth(),
        slideHeight = $('.suga-slide').height(),
      slideCount = $slide.length,
      totalWidth = slideWidth * slideCount;

  // set width on group element
  $group.width(totalWidth);
  $wrap.height(slideHeight);
  $wrap.wrap('<div class="suga-container"></div>');

  // add first class at start
  if (!$group.find($firstEl).hasClass("suga-first")) {
    $group.find($firstEl).addClass("suga-first");
  }

  // lets move baby
  var transitionSnap = function() {
    var $firstEl = $group.find('.suga-first').html();

    $group.find('.suga-first').animate({
      'margin-left': '-' + slideWidth + 'px'
    }, function(){
     $group.append('<li class="suga-slide">' + $firstEl + '</li>');
     $(this).remove(); 
     $group.find('li:first').addClass("suga-first");

    });  
  };

  var transitionScroll = function() {
     var $firstEl = $group.find('.suga-first').html();

    $group.find('.suga-first').animate({
      'margin-left': '-' + slideWidth + 'px'
    }, settings.transitionSpeed, 'linear', function(){
     $group.append('<li class="suga-slide">' + $firstEl + '</li>');
     $(this).remove(); 
     $group.find('li:first').addClass("suga-first");
     transitionScroll();
    });       
  };

  if (settings.snap) {
    window.setInterval(transitionSnap, settings.transitionSpeed);  
  } else {
    transitionScroll();
  }
}

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#logos').suga({
    'transitionSpeed': 2000,
    'snap': true
  });
});
</script>
<style>
.mixingservice {
    background : url("img/parallaxstudio.jpg") repeat fixed 100%;
     background-size: cover;

} 
.general {
    background : url("img/parallaxmain1.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.distribution {
    background : url("img/parallaxdistribution.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.webdesign {
    background : url("img/webservice.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.featuredmusic {
    background : url("img/featured.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

$bg-color: #d9d8c6;
$primary-color: #5b5a5c;
$secondary-color: darken($primary-color, 15%);

body {
  background: $bg-color;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.suga-container {
  background: $primary-color;
  padding: 3px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 3px auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px $secondary-color;
  border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.suga-slider-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 3px;
}

.suga-slider-group {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}

.suga-slide {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<!-- Promo Banners -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide row" data-ride="carousel" height="400px">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/banner101.jpg"  height="590px" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/digigodbanner.jpg"  height="590px" alt="DigiGod slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/banner2.jpg"  height="590px" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>

<!--Introduction-->
<div class="general row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="420" width="420"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <br><font color="white"><h1>ILLUMONOPOLY</h1></font>
        <hr style="background-color:#ffffff">
            <div class="box"><br> 
                Welcome to the official website of ILLUMONOPOLY. The Digital Media Mantra. Providing independent businesses and musicians with marketable media solutions to expand thier brands for over 10 years. 
                Its Not what can we do for you. Its more of what cant we do for you. With our dedicated team and staff we can help you evolve your brand to the next level. Let Us Expand Your Brand, Your Sound, Your Visual Production, Your fanbase, Your Social media & web presence.<br><B>LET US HELP YOU EXPAND YOUR BRAND!!!!</b>
                </font>
            </div><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Featured Music-->
<div class="featuredmusic row">             <br><br><Br>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
        <img src="/img/Do%20ME.jpg" class="img-fluid">  <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js?external-type=html"></script> 
 <div class="powr-countdown-timer" id="a2995a09_1517179632"></div><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
        <img src="/img/BMW2.jpg" class="img-fluid"><hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js?external-type=html"></script> 
 <div class="powr-countdown-timer" id="5f7b3d0c_1517204663"></div><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
        <img src="/img/trillegaltender.jpg" class="img-fluid"><hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js?external-type=html"></script> 
 <div class="powr-countdown-timer" id="8d9a22a1_1517191024"></div><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
        <img src="/img/digigod%20Album.jpg" class="img-fluid"><hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js?external-type=html"></script> 
 <div class="powr-countdown-timer" id="756a9078_1517191543"></div><br>
    </div>
        <br><br><br>        
</div>
<!--mixingservice-->
<div class="mixingservice row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/mixservice.png" class="img-fluid"><br>
        <H1>CLIENTS</H1><hr style="background-color:#ffffff">
        <font size="3vh">
        Tory Lanes, Ron Browz, 2 Chainz, J-Hard 360, Dezzy Chamberland, Sig Music, ZaeTheGodd and more....<br>
        </font><br>
        <a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="background-color:"red" >Order Now</button></a>        
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>  
<!--DIVIDER-->
<div class="general row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br><br>
        <h1><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="100" width="100"> expanding brands for the Last decade</h1>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Artist SPotlight-->
<div class="featuredmusic row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 box">
            <iframe width="100%" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Na8I8cowXiw?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 box">
            <iframe width="100%" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWU4e6kFaaw?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
<!--Distribution-->
<div class="distribution row">  
    <div class="col-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/iphone.png" height="500" width="360">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="padding-top: 30px;  padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <img src="img/distrotext2.png" class="img-fluid">
        <br>
        <img src="img/streams.png" class="img-fluid">
        <br><a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color:#000000">Sign Up</button></a>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Client Logos-->
<center>Previous Clients</center><br>
<div id="logos" class="container">

  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/bobbyvlogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/dtplogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/premierlogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/cokeboyslogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/thisis50logo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/padrinologo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
     <li><img src="img/neuflogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
     <li><img src="img/akamailogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
     <li><img src="img/dufflebaglogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
     <li><img src="img/streetfelonslogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/paylesslogo.png" width="100px" height="80px" /></li>
       <li><img src="img/millyslogo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></li>
     <li><img src="img/giselle.png" width="90px" height="100px" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--Artist SPotlight-->

<!--application-->
<div class="webdesign row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <br><br>
        <img src="img/mactop.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <br><br>
            <div class="container-fluid box">
                <font color="white" size="5vh"><h1>Web & Application Developement</h1><br></font>   
                 Are You In Need of a Website? And or an Mobile Application? <br>
                 Our Team of developers can get your brand up and running and designed to your specifications in just a week.
                 Inquire via email for questions and quotes for custom designs and scripts, websites and applications. 
                 <br>No JOB TOO BIG NO JOB TOO SMALL. LET US EXPAND YOUR BRAND!!!!!<br><br>
                 <a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color:#666666">Inquire Now</button></a>
                 <br><br>
            </div><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<!--googleAdSense--><br><br>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7512006871298343"
     data-ad-slot="7265345115"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>



<!--footer-->
&copy; ILLUMONOPOLY LLC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. 
<br><br><Br> 
</center><br><br><br>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make this compatible when responsive, use some framework such as bootstrap.
It is a skeleton you could work for and no need of changing the logic or scripts.

Comment: I am using bootstrap It is loaded via ajax threw the index page which loading this page and other internal content into a Div

Comment: First, I should say, your html structure is not properly done with the bootstrap classes. Correct that first.
Secondly, your page has 9 script errors, try to fix that, some warning and error related to jQuery loading. Fix those errors.
HTML should wrap around a container, then layout elements such as col-md-12, col-md-6, col-sm-12, etc.... I do not see any classes related to layout in your source code.